# I have this stored procedure and I want to revise it to be to rebuild more than one index in SQL

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have this stored procedure and I want to revise it to be to rebuild more than one index.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

ALTER PROCEDURE [Landing].[usp_IndexDisableRebuild] 
    (@Schema_Name VARCHAR(256),
     @Table_Name VARCHAR(256), 
     @Task_Name VARCHAR(256))
AS
    -- Set to get the dynamic Script for
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = (SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(I.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(T.name) + @Task_Name FROM sys.indexes I INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON I.object_id = T.object_id INNER Join sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id WHERE I.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' AND I.name IS NOT NULL --AND I.is_disabled = 0 AND t.name = @Table_Name AND s.name = @Schema_Name )

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL
    EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: I just want to revise the stored procedure to rebuild multiple indexes.  Its currently giving me this error  Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spInParam, Line 11
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel *yet again* ? Just use the [Ola Hallengren Index Rebuild magic tools](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) and be done with it - forever! :-)

Comment: can anybody help with the above

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that you should consider using [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

That being said, you could change your proc like to example below. In addition to correcting the subquery error, this uses the proper data types. Not sure what you want to do with @Task_Name so I just appended the value as a comment.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Landing].[usp_IndexDisableRebuild] 
    @Schema_Name sysname,
    @Table_Name sysname, 
    @Task_Name VARCHAR(256)
AS
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = (
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(I.name) 
        + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(T.name) + ' REBUILD;
--' + @Task_Name + '
'
FROM sys.indexes I 
INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON I.object_id = T.object_id 
INNER Join sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id 
WHERE I.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' 
    AND I.name IS NOT NULL
    AND I.is_disabled = 0 
    AND t.name = @Table_Name
    AND s.name = @Schema_Name
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)');
--PRINT @SQL;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```